# How do I get the text of my WordPress posts left indented?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the theme "blogito" for my WordPress blog.
In my articles, the text (`<p>`) is weirdly right indented and in some browsers you cant see the whole text.

How do I get a left indentation, so the text is aligned with the pictures.
On this post page you can see what I mean:

https://couch-investing.de/shopdoc-das-allrounder-tool-fuer-amazon-verkaeufer/

Does that have something to do with the class `entry-content col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-push-2`?

I'm really bad at JavaScript and CSS and would be happy about your help :)

Cheers

Rob

Comment: Yes as your theme uses Bootstrap, there is one column offset is added on left side. removing class **"col-lg-offset-1"** from your most probably from **single.php** file. In not fund in single file then remove check respective template in template-part directory.

Comment: Thanks, i found it there but when i try to delete it says: It was not possible to communicate with the website to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change has been undone. You will need to upload your modified PHP file by...

Answer (score 0):

You have offset set for the content area 
find this line in the code

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
```

and remove `col-lg-offset-1` for better placement of text

like this :

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-lg-10">
```

Comment: Thank you, i found the part in single.php:           <?php $blogito_is_active_sidebar = ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ? '' : ' col-lg-offset-2' ); ?>
<div class="row">
 <div id="primary" class="content-area<?php echo ( $blogito_has_sidebar ? ' col-lg-8' . $blogito_is_active_sidebar : ' col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1' )  I tried deleting ...offset-1, should i also delete the upper ...offset-2. It gave me the following error: 
It was not possible to communicate with the website to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change has been undone. You will need to upload your modified PHP file by...

Comment: Do not delete the upper offset 2 because its of sidebar.